# What is it called when people use words like ur and u in place of your, and you?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, slang

And why do people say it's lazy and bad? Why do people call others stupid for it, when it's intentional and I don't really think its wrong in casual conversations through text (obviously not speech)

I didn't really know what to tag it as since  I am ignorant.

Comment: In *speech*, no-one would recognise the "self-referentiality" (I forget the technical term for it), but in writing you could go for [**Txting**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22txting%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl). The Guardian article in that link explores whether it's *for people who can't spell or write*, so it would probably interest you. (Or shud I say *intrest **u**?* :)

Answer (score 0):

**SMS language** — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language)

> SMS language or textese (also known as txt-speak, txtese, chatspeak, txt, txtspk, txtk, txto, texting language, txt lingo, SMSish, txtslang, txt talk) is a term for the abbreviations and slang commonly used with mobile phone text messaging, but sometimes used with other Internet-based communication such as email and instant messaging.
>
> Once it became popular it took on a life of its own and was often used outside of its original context. At its peak, it was the cause of vigorous debate about its potentially detrimental effect on literacy, but with the advent of alphabetic keyboards on smartphones its use, and the controversies surrounding it, have receded